# Hadoop mapreduce on MongoDB using java

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm working on a MongoDB structure that has a tree structure.. as given in this link 
([see docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/))

I would like to know what will be passed in the key in the map method. Is it the topmost parent in the tree ans should i iterate to get my value list.

I have a tree structure that has company as parent and company name, website,product etc as children. The product will in turn have product name as its child.

So, if i need the company name to be the key, how should i get it using java?

What will be the key here - company ?

If there is any sample program or documentation for doing mapreduce over mongoDB in java, can anyone please provide me asap?

Thanks

Comment: There's an example of Map Reduce via the Java driver here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/mapreduce-with-mongodb.html.  I found that by putting "mongodb map reduce java" into Google, where there were plenty more answers...

Comment: Thanks Trisha. The above link is doing the in-built map reduce thats available in MongoDB. I wanted an example for a Map Reduce using Hadoop and MongoDB. I have finally figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Trisha. The above link is doing the in-built map reduce thats available in MongoDB. I wanted an example for a Map Reduce using Hadoop and MongoDB. I have finally figured it out.

```
public static class MongoMapper extends
        Mapper<Object, BasicDBObject, Text, BSONWritable> {


    public void map(Object key, BasicDBObject value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        //This gives all the documents of the company
        BasicDBObject company = (BasicDBObject) value.get("company");

        // This gets the company name
        name = (String) company.get("name");

        //This gives the phone number 
        phone = (String) company.get("phone");
```

If we need to access the product list in company we can retrieve using a BasicDBList

```
// This will give the list of products and we can use product.get()
// to get the product name and other details. 
BasicDBList product = (BasicDBList) company.get("products");
```

I referred to this slideshare link.

http://www.slideshare.net/spf13/introduction-to-mongodb-and-hadoop

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer.  There's very little in there that's specific to Hadoop - BasicDBObject and its methods are part of the standard MongoDB Java driver.  Only the fact that you're extending Mapper is Hadoop-specific, but you don't seem to be implementing an actual map function (more examples here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/examples/README.md).  Do you really need Hadoop?